# Print pdf and html document from android mobile

Tags: android

My app having pdf and html documents. I need to implement print functionality in that app. So please provide some sample pdf printer code for android.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks but that code is for Google cloud print. But i need direct print code example other than Google Cloud Print

Comment: "that code is for Google cloud print" -- no, it is not. It is for the Android 4.4+ printing framework. "i need direct print code example other than Google Cloud Print" -- either use the Android 4.4+ printing framework, or contact your printer manufacturer and ask them if they have "direct print code example other than Google Cloud Print" for their particular printer.

Comment: Hi commonsware i used that Android 4.4+ printing framework code but that code always going to google drive. I want to design print functionality like printershare android app. Pls provide some ideas to implement that

Comment: I do not see anything in those samples that have anything to do with Google Drive. [This sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Printing/PrintManager) definitely has nothing to do with Google Drive, as I do not use Google Drive. Please bear in mind that your device needs an app associated with your printer, that offers the Android equivalent of the print drivers that you use on desktop operating systems. [This one is for HP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.android.printservice), for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your valuable comment. I have one doubt actually you mentioned "that your device needs an app associated with your printer". My app is for users and i need to support all printers. can you guide me to achieve this